# Select hidden elements and manipulate them with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Within a div wrapper with a class of "section", I have dozens of HTML elements repeated across the page that look like this:

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
</div>
```

And each contains certain information inside. Now, what I'm trying to do is once the page loads, show only the first 5, hide the rest in a new div inserted with jQuery, and when this new div is clicked it will display the next five , and then the next five on click again, and so on until the end. The idea is that this new div will function as a button that will always be positioned at the end of the page and will respond to these orders I just mentioned. So far I've got this down:

```
$('.section').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $allArticles = $this.find('.article');

    if ($allArticles.length > 5) {
        $('<div/>').addClass('hidden-articles').appendTo(this).append($allArticles.slice(5));
        $('.hidden-articles .article').hide();
    }
});
```

And that hides all but the first five. But now for the rest of the process, I can't get it to work. I don't seem to be able to select properly those hidden div with class "article" and manipulate them to function the way I described above. I would appreciate it a lot if someone more experienced with jQuery could guide me in the right direction and maybe offer a snippet. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You should post your `HTML` code here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the :hidden and :lt selectors to get the functionality you are looking for..

```
$('.section').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $allArticles = $this.find('.article');

    if ($allArticles.length > 5) {
        $('<div/>').addClass('hidden-articles')
                   .appendTo(this).append($allArticles.slice(5));
        $this.find('.hidden-articles .article').hide();

    }
});

$('#show').on('click',function() {
    var $hidden = $('.hidden-articles .article:hidden:lt(5)');
    $hidden.show();
});​
```

**UPDATE**

```
// If one one element to search 
var elem = '.section' ;
hideArticles(elem);

// If Multiple Elements on the page...
$('.section').each(function() {
    hideArticles(this);
});

$('#show').on('click', function() {
    var $hidden = $('.hidden-articles .article:hidden:lt(5)');
    $hidden.show();
});

function hideArticles(elem) {
    var $this = $(elem),
        $allArticles = $this.find('.article');

    if ($allArticles.length > 5) {
        $('<div/>').addClass('hidden-articles')
                   .appendTo(this).append($allArticles.slice(5));
        $this.find('.hidden-articles .article').hide();
    }
}​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jBkp6/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. It's close to what I was after, and I'd up your post if I could. However, the problem is that clicking on a toggle button will display everything that's been hidden within a section, which could be dozens of items, and I'm just looking for a way to display the next five, and then the next five again on click, not just one batch of elements. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfHqC/) I just created for you to see. How can I create a button that will always sit at the end of the page and reveal a group of articles dynamically once it's clicked? Thanks again!

Comment: @Sushanth.. you're super! That's the concept that I was looking for and I have now adapted the code to suit my needs. Really helpful. I've got a quick question for you: say that I didn't want to run the .each() method on the .section selector because there will only be **one** like that in the entire document. I'm thinking that moving all the code inside the .each() method to a new function is a good option, but then is there a way I can pass on the selector to my new function? How would you recommend I did this? Thank you!

Comment: @Annabel .. You are welcome :) ..  If thats the case then you can just pass the `this` object to the function , as that is the only one that is required.. I have updated the post with the approach I can think of right now..